# Using segment labels in ggplot with ggrepel with smooth segments

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(year = c(1984, 1984), team = c("Australia", "Brazil"
), continent = c("Oceania", "Americas"), medal = structure(c(3L, 
3L), .Label = c("Bronze", "Silver", "Gold"), class = "factor"), 
    n = c(84L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is my ggplot (my question is related to the annotations regard Brazil label):

```
ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y = n)) + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = year, y = n, label = team),
                  size = 3, color = 'black',
                  seed = 10,
                  nudge_x = -.029,
                  nudge_y = 35,
                  segment.size = .65,
                  segment.curvature = -1,
                  segment.angle = 178.975,
                  segment.ncp = 1)+ 
  coord_flip()
```

So, I have a segment divided by two parts. On both parts I have 'small braks'. How can I avoid them?

I already tried to use `segment.ncp`, change `nudge_x`or `nudge_y`nut its not working.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: Could you include an image of what you are getting and highlight what you want changing. Assume you mean 'small breaks' were do you see these breaks? When I run your example the  segments seem to fine: one continuous line .

Comment: Ok @Peter just a sec.

Comment: I circled the parts of the segment that are bothering me. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried resizing your plot window or saving the plot? This might already fix the issue. When I run your example everything looks good.

Comment: @Mojoesque thanks for your time. For example, when I save with  `width: 745`and `height: 314`  it improves but still have only one "break" on the first segemnt. Very weird I have to try every single width/height for this to improve my plot.

Comment: what format are you saving the file as? Try to save it as a vector graphic (pdf for example) if you are not already doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what is going on here. This is the best I could generate by experimenting with variations to the input values for `segment...` arguments.

There is some guidance at: https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html which has an example with shorter leader lines, maybe that's an approach you could use.

```r
df<-structure(list(year = c(1984, 1984), team = c("Australia", "Brazil"
), continent = c("Oceania", "Americas"), medal = structure(c(3L, 
                                                             3L), .Label = c("Bronze", "Silver", "Gold"), class = "factor"), 
n = c(84L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y = n)) + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = year, y = n, label = team),
                  size = 3, color = 'black',
                  seed = 1,
                  nudge_x = -0.029,
                  nudge_y = 35,
                  segment.size = 0.5,
                  segment.curvature = -0.0000002,
                  segment.angle = 1,
                  segment.ncp = 1000)+ 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: many thanks. I think the point is: why with my settings I need to save as pdf to have the exactly plot as yours? To improve my plot you had to change the values.